# Using Java to implement a hash table (dictionary) with only arrays

Tags: java, hash-map, hashcode

I'm new to hash codes/hash tables, so I'm very unsure of my implementation. I want to create a hash table, but I can only use arrays. Specifically, I want to be able to insert things like a dictionary (a word and its meaning). Here is what I have:

```
public class HashTable {
    String[][] table;
    int tableSize;

    HashTable(int size) {
        table = new String[size][];
        tableSize = size;
    }

    public void add(String key, String value) {

        if (key == null || value == null) {
            System.out.println("Cannot input null values");
        }

        int iter = 0;
        int code = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % tableSize;

        if (table[code] == null) {
            table[code] = new String[]{key, value};
        } else {

            while (table[code] != null) {
                if (table[code][0].equals(key)) {
                    System.out.println("Already submitted submitted the word " + key);
                    return;
                }

                if (iter == tableSize) {
                    System.out.println("Table is full. Cannot add word \"" + key + "\"");
                    return;
                }

                code++;
                code %= tableSize;
                iter++;
            }

            table[code] = new String[]{key, value};

        }
    }

    public void remove(String key) {

        if (key == null) {
            System.out.println("Cannot input null value");
        }

        int iter = 0;
        int code = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % tableSize;

        if (table[code][0].equals(key)) {
            table[code] = null;
        } else {
            while (!table[code][0].equals(key)) {
                if (iter == tableSize) {
                    System.out.println("Could not find word \"" + key + "\"");
                    return;
                }
                code++;
                code %= tableSize;
                iter++;
            }

            table[code] = null;

        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {

        if (key == null) {
            return "Cannot input null value.";
        }

        int iter = 0;
        int code = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % tableSize;

        if (table[code][0].equals(key)) {
            return table[code][1];
        } else {
            while (!table[code][0].equals(key)) {
                if (iter == tableSize) {
                    return "Could not find word \"" + key + "\"";
                }
                code++;
                code %= tableSize;
                iter++;
            }

            return table[code][1];

        }
    }

}
```

Is this an okay implementation? How can I make it better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Do not special case an immediate success. The test for `table[code] == null` in

  ```
      if (table[code] == null) {
          table[code] = new String[]{key, value};
      } else {
          while (table[code] != null) {
          ....
  ```

  does not do anything useful, but only adds noise. Dive into the loop immediately.

  Ditto for `table[code][0].equals(key)` in `remove` and `get`.
- Such low level utility functions shall not `System.out.println` (in any case, an error message shall go to `System.err`). Prefer returning an error code, and let the caller decide what to do.
- It is unclear how well [`String.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) is suited for this design of a hash table. Depending on the table size, you may get plenty of collisions. Using `Math.abs` on a hash code also biases the distribution. Need to measure.